# Google Maps API must now use a Server Key?

Tags: google-maps

My website makes use of Google Maps API. I recently received an email from Google that says that I should switch from a Browser Key to a Server Key in order to continue using the API past 2 Dec 2015.

So if I am not mistaken all I have to do is request a Server Key in the Google Console and put it in place of my Bowser Key? is that simple?

Here is part of the email:

> Yesterday, we announced a pay-as-you-go option for seven of the Google
>   Maps API Web Services for free, external, publicly available websites
>   and mobile implementations. As part of this launch, we are tightening
>   security around how developers identify their usage of the APIs. You
>   are receiving this email because you may be affected by this change.
>
> Starting today we have deprecated usage of 'Keys for browser
>   applications' or 'Browser keys’ with the Google Maps API Web Services.
>   Developers should instead use ‘Server keys’ with these services. Any
>   newly created browser keys will not work, but existing browser keys
>   will continue to work for 90 days starting today. On 2nd December
>   2015, we will be completely disabling usage of browser keys to access
>   Google Maps API Web Services, at which point any requests to Google
>   Maps Web Services APIs using such keys will begin to fail.

Currently, in my HTML I have the following that loads the Google Maps API:

```
<script scr="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&signed_in=false&key=MY_BROWSER_API_KEY&sensor=false"></script>
```

In another page in the same website, I use the YouTube Data API in the server side to which I feed the SERVER_KEY I obtained from Google Console.
The code looks like:

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey(GOOGLE_API_SERVER_KEY);
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
```

Comment: Sounds correct from what *you* said, but don't know what the email said...  Which API are you using?  How are you using it?  I wouldn't expect you to need a server key for a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map, but for any of the webservices that would make sense.

Comment: Yes. I am using the Google Maps Javascript API v3. It doesn't make sense to me to feed Javascript a Server Key.

Comment: From the text you posted, you are using a browser key in one of the API web services, which will no longer be allowed.  Impossible to tell where you are doing that as you haven't provided any of your code.

Comment: I have a script tag in my HTML that loads the Maps API https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&signed_in=false

Comment: You aren't using a webservice anywhere else or on that page? (or in any other processing on your server)

Comment: I am using a service. I use the YouTube Data API (server side) in another page to which I feed the SERVER_KEY

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you have to do is change out the key.  There are complications with white lists, that may or may not affect people. The white lists between server and web keys need to be merged. This is a problem if the server does not send outgoing communications with the same ip address everytime. For example, for my company, our set up is a group of instances that get dynamically assigned ips from a public pool. In our case we are going to add an extra network interface.

So a better answer to your question is depending on whether you only use the key in a public webpage, or if you use it on a server. If you use the key on a server, and the key is connected to a paid google account for a specific map api service, then you will have to figure out the outgoing ip address(es) and add each one to the list.

A lot of people, particularly on shared hosting accounts have not white listed the server ip as until now, as it could be hidden and the risks of people pirating the key were minimal. But now, in the next 90 days, a lot of private server keys are going to be publicly exposed  when people also have to put the key in their html. This will probably mean that there will be a mini migration from shared hosting to more controlled environments, in my opinion.